# Apache2 Rewrite Rules result in 404

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 lts with Apache 2. I enabled mod_rewrite, but when my rules are enabled it results in a 404 error.

This is my current (stripped down) .htaccess file and I still get a 404:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?page=$1
```

I've configured my virtualhost like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website
    ServerAlias www.website
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/website/>                                                                                                     
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews                                                                               
         AllowOverride All                                                                                                       
         Require all granted                                                                                             
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What have I done wrong? It works on IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm already solved it, somehow the MultiViews option was causing trouble or I made a type error.

replaced

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

with this

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

And it works now